# MariaDB-JSON-document- Not able to select only specific elements from array without knowing his index after applying exact where clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariasql, mariadb-10.3, json-extract

I have JSON document. structure/sample data is like -

```
{
   "id":"201",
   "portfolio":[
      {
         "portfolio_id":"PORTFOLIO_001",
         "portfolio_name":"AAA",
         "product":[
            {
               "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001",
               "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_1",
               "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_NAME"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002",
               "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_1",
               "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_NAME"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "portfolio_id":"PORTFOLIO_002",
         "portfolio_name":"BBB",
         "product":[
            {
               "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001",
               "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001_1",
               "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001_NAME"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have written select SQL as below. I want to fetch products of that specific portfolio(PORTFOLIO_001) and id. I am getting all products of all portfolios instead of products of specific portfolio(PORTFOLIO_001)

```
SELECT json_extract(j, '$.portfolio[*].product') FROM t WHERE json_contains(json_extract(j, '$.portfolio[*].portfolio_id'), '"PORTFOLIO_001"') AND JSON_CONTAINS(j, '"201"', '$.id')
```

Actual output -

```
[
   [
      {
         "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001",
         "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_1",
         "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_NAME"
      },
      {
         "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002",
         "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_1",
         "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_NAME"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001",
         "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001_1",
         "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_002_PRODUCT_001_NAME"
      }
   ]
]
```

Expected output -

```
[
    {
     "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001",
     "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_1",
     "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_001_NAME"
    },
    {
     "product_id":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002",
     "product_trigram":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_1",
     "product_name":"PORTFOLIO_001_PRODUCT_002_NAME"
    }
]
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your action :-)

Regards,
Prashant

Comment: `'$.portfolio[0].product'` ?

Comment: @Akina, If I put in such a way then it will always returns the 1st element from array. In that case if I filter on PORTFOLIO_002 then also it will return me the products of PORTFOLIO_001

Comment: If so then use nested extraction (subquery or CTE). Firstly extract $.portfolio from the object where $.id = 201, then extract $.product from the object where $.portfolio_id = 'PORTFOLIO_001'

Comment: It returns the array. Same problem for index as we are getting in old(first) SQL